# Fredholm index for 1-d Schroedinger operator

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

if I look at a Schroedinger-operator $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +V$ on a compact intervall $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and I take boundary conditions that this operator is self-adjoint (for example periodic ones). $V$ shall be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Is it always true ( no matter what the potential explicitely is) that the Fredholm index is zero?

Comment: I imagine (but should confirm) that if you're doing periodic BC's then you also have a periodic potential. (I.e. no jump at the edges of the interval.)

Comment: okay,I had a periodic potential in mind when I wrote down e.g. periodic BC's, but if you are able to answer more generally, then I would also be interested in this case :-). but yes, you can assume that the potential is supposed to be periodic too.

Comment: Oh, I figured. I just wanted to make sure any pathology was eliminated. (Which is to say, your potential should of course be coherent with your imposed BCs)

Comment: I think everything is okay without periodicity of $V$. $V \in L^{\infty}[a,b]$ with $V$ real should be enough so that $Hf = -f''+Vf$ is Fredholm with index $0$ on $L^{2}[a,b]$. The domain would be the set of $f$ which are twice absolutely continuous on $(a,b)$, with $f$, $f'$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and with $Hf \in L^{2}[a,b]$ (and, of course periodic $f$, $f'$.) I think you might be able to relax conditions to allow a real $V \in L^{1}[a,b]$, but I'd have to check on that.

Comment: @T.A.E. thank you. is it difficult to show this?-Especially, that the index is actually zero.

Comment: That's the real beauty of Sturm-Liouville Theory: you can write down the resolvent operator $(H-\lambda I)^{-1}$ as a function of $\lambda$, and invoke classical ODE theory. The PDE formulations require abstract techniques, but Sturm-Liouville you can write down, at least well enough to feel like you know exactly what you're doing. To write down general solutions, all you need is (a) the classical eigenfunctions of the ODE which exist for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and (b) variation of parameters. Periodic is messier to satisfy the endpoint conditions, but it's basically algebra.

Comment: Note: If $H$ is selfadjoint, then $\mathcal{N}(H)=\mathcal{R}(H)^{\perp}$. So, if you know the range of $H$ is of finite co-dimension, then the index of $H$ has to be $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Classical Solutions:** First, assume $V\in L^{1}[a,b]$, and show the existence of classical solutions of
$$
          -f''+Vf = \lambda f,\;\;\; f(a)=A,\;f'(a)=B.
$$
This can be done by considering the equivalent integral equation
$$
           f(x)=A+B(x-a)+\int_{a}^{x}\int_{a}^{t}(V(u)-\lambda)f(u)\,du\,dv.
$$
This is a fixed point problem for $C[a,b]$ associated with the function
$$
             Kf = A+B(x-a)+\int_{a}^{x}\int_{a}^{t}(V(u)-\lambda)f(u)\,du\,dv.
$$
By restricting to a smaller interval $[a,b']$ if necessary, you get a contractive map
$$
\begin{align}
       \|Kf-Kg\|_{C[a,b']} 
           & \le \int_{a}^{x}\int_{a}^{t}|V(u)-\lambda|\,du\,dv\cdot\|f-g\|_{C[a,b']} \\
           & \le \left[\|V(u)-\lambda\|_{L^{1}[a,b]}(b'-a)\right]\|f-g\|_{C[a,b']}
\end{align}
$$
This leads to integral operators that are contractive on each interval $[a_{k}',b_{k}']$ of a finite partition of $[a,b]$. You can stitch solutions together by taking values of $f$, $f'$ at the right-endpoint of a partition interval to use as $A$, $B$ on the next interval. This gives a solution of the original ODE on the full interval $[a,b]$. The solution on each interval is a sum of iterated integrals, and it is not hard to show that $\lambda \mapsto f_{\lambda}(x)$ is an entire function of $\lambda$ for fixed $x$. The solution $f_{\lambda}$ is a solution of the integral equation, and that gives you classical differentiability: $f_{\lambda}$ is continuously differentiable and $f_{\lambda}'$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ with $f_{\lambda}''=(V-\lambda)f$ a.e.. These solutions are unique.

**Green Function:** Choose the unique solutions $\phi_{\lambda}$ and $\psi_{\lambda}$ of $-f''+Vf=\lambda f$ which satisfy
$$
             \phi_{\lambda}(a)=1,\; \phi_{\lambda}'(a)=0,\\ \psi_{\lambda}(a)=0,\;\psi_{\lambda}'(a)=1.
$$
Any solution of $f$ of $-f''+Vf =\lambda$ can be written as $f=f(a)\phi_{\lambda}+f'(a)\psi_{\lambda}$ because of uniqueness of such solutions.

The Wronskian $W(\phi_{\lambda},\psi_{\lambda})=\phi_{\lambda}\psi_{\lambda}'-\phi_{\lambda}'\psi_{\lambda}$ is constant on $[a,b]$ because its derivative is $0$. And the Wronskian at $a$ is $1$. So the Wronskian is identically $1$. Using this, you can verify that the general solution of the inhomogenous equation $-f''+(V-\lambda)f = g$ has the form
$$
          f(x) = \psi_{\lambda}(x)\int_{a}^{x}\phi_{\lambda}(t)g(t)\,dt
                -\phi_{\lambda}(x)\int_{a}^{x}\psi_{\lambda}(t)g(t)\,dt
               +A\psi_{\lambda}(x)+B\phi_{\lambda}(x).
$$
It is easy to verify that $f$ is twice absolutely continuous with $f'' \in L^{1}[a,b]$.
Let $\mathscr{I}_{\lambda}g$ denote the integral terms. The function $h=\mathscr{I}_{\lambda}g$ is the unique solution of
$$
                  -h''+(V-\lambda)h = g,\\
                   h(a)=h'(a) =0.
$$
The constants $A$ and $B$ are determined from any required endpoint conditions required for a given solution.

You are interested in solutions $f$ of $-f''+(V-\lambda)f=g$ where $f(a)=f(b)$, $f'(a)=f'(b)$, and that's the next topic. For convenience, define $\Delta h = h(b)-h(a)$ and $\Delta' h=h'(b)-h'(a)$. There is a periodic solution $f$ iff $\Delta f=\Delta' f = 0$ for some such $f$. That comes down to being able to solve a $2\times 2$ system for constants $A$ and $B$ such that
$$
        \left[\begin{array}{c}\Delta f \\ \Delta'f\end{array}\right]=
    \left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\0\end{array}\right]
     = \left[\begin{array}{c}\Delta\mathscr{I}_{\lambda}g \\ \Delta'\mathscr{L}_{\lambda}g\end{array}\right] + 
       \left[\begin{array}{cc}
             \Delta\phi_{\lambda} & \Delta\psi_{\lambda} \\
             \Delta'\phi_{\lambda} & \Delta'\psi_{\lambda}
            \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}A \\ B\end{array}\right].
$$
This equation can definitely be solved if the determinant $D(\lambda)$ of the $2\times 2$ matrix on the right is non-zero. Notice that $D(\lambda)$ is an entire function of $\lambda$. So $D$ has only a discrete set of zeros that cannot accumulate anywhere in the finite plane. Using Sturm-Liouville arguments, the zeros of $D$ must also lie on the real line. Given $g \in L^{1}[a,b]$, for all $\lambda$ for which $D(\lambda) \ne 0$ there is a unique classical solution $f_{\lambda}$ of
$$
               -f_{\lambda}''+(V-\lambda)f_{\lambda} = g\\
                  f(a)=f(b),\;\; f'(a)=f'(b).
$$
So, for all such $\lambda$, the Fredholm index is $0$ on $L^{1}[a,b]$. If $D(\lambda)=0$, then there are constants $A$ and $B$ which are not both $0$ such that $f=A\phi_{\lambda}+B\psi_{\lambda}$ satisfies $\Delta f=\Delta' f=0$. That is, if $D(\lambda)=0$, then there is a non-zero periodic eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda$. In this case the nullity index is either $1$ or $2$. In the case that $D(\lambda)=0$, you can show that there is a unique solution of
$$
                       -f''+(V-\lambda)f = g,\\
                       f(a)=f(b),\;f'(a)=f'(b)
$$
iff $g$ satisfies $\int_{a}^{b}g(t)h(t)\,dt =0$
for every solution $h$ of the periodic eigenfunction problem
$$
                             -h''+(V-\lambda)h =0,\\
                             h(a)=h(b),\; h'(a)=h(b).
$$
I'll give you a hint to prove this last part: This ties in directly with the Green function solution where evaluations at $b$ involve such integrals.

Because of this, the nullity and deficiency indices are the same, regardless of whether or not $D(\lambda)=0$. Restricting to $L^{2}$ gives the same result. But the result is generally true on any $L^{p}$, $1 \le p < \infty$, if $V \in L^{1}[a,b]$.

Comment: By the way, the order of the zero of $D$ is the dimension of the periodic eigenspace, which is either $1$ or $2$. You can carry out this construction for $V=0$, and should see how that case works. You end up with $D$ with a first order $0$ at $0$ and second order zeros at $1^{2},2^{2},3^{2},\cdots$. There's a really subtle issue that comes up at $\lambda=0$ and you should see it. Please try. You'll be amazed at how all the $\sqrt{\lambda}$ terms conspire just right to give entire expressions. So, even the simplest case is subtle and important. And explict.

Comment: What I meant in the previous comment is to assume $V=0$ and find eigenfunction solutions $\phi_{\lambda}$, $\psi_{\lambda}$ that satisfy the conditions stated in the write-up. Then find $D$, which becomes and explicit function of $\lambda$. Go through the full solution process to find the final solution operator $(L-\lambda I)^{-1}$ except where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. This will involve $D$. Convince yourself that $D$ has a first order $0$ at $0$ and a second order $0$ the other eigenvalues. Verify the dimensions of the eigenspaces. This shows the pattern that is true in general.